# "IndexError: list index out of range" when 1 specific condition isn't met

Tags: python, list, function

The code still finds the correct phone numbers but gives an error for the phone number that doesn't match the xxx-xxx-xxxx format.

Why doesn't an error occur for each loop, but instead only presents itself for the number with xxxx-xxx-xxx format

I've tried using 'except' function and the python visualiser. The code works without error if I only keep 1 if statement to check the length of digits[0]

Thanks guys!

Code:

```
def numCheck(digits):
    digits = digits.split('-')
    if len(digits[0]) != 3:
        return False
    if len(digits[1]) != 3:
        return False
    if len(digits[2]) != 4:
        return False
    joinDigits = ''.join(digits)
    if not joinDigits.isdecimal():
        return False
    if len(joinDigits) != 10:
        return False
    else:
        return True

phoneNo = ('nec dictum tellus. Fusce vitae 2222-345-678 risus ac. Aenean condimentum 124-567-6893 e. Pelunt erat fermentum. Nulla vel fes 234-574-1111 sapien quam sed.')

isNum = False

for i in range(len(phoneNo)):
    sweep = phoneNo[i:i+12]

    if numCheck(sweep):
        print('We found a number: ' + sweep)
        isNum = True

if not isNum:
        print('We couldn\'t find a number')
```

Result:

```
We found a number: 124-567-6893
We found a number: 234-574-1111

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnny/Desktop/Python/testing .py", line 26, in <module>
    if numCheck(sweep):
  File "/Users/johnny/Desktop/Python/testing .py", line 7, in numCheck
    if len(digits[1]) != 3:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this part:

```
for i in range(len(phoneNo)):
    sweep = phoneNo[i:i+12]
```

You would want to do something like this:

```
for i in range(len(phoneNo)-12):
    sweep = phoneNo[i:i+12]
```

This is because in the last 12 iterations of this for, you are trying to slice far over the end of the list.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sort of.  This solves the problem but I think you need to add more information to explain what's really happening.  To be clear, you are very much allowed to slice beyond the end of the list.  What you can't do is access an index beyond the end of a list.  So if a = [1, 2, 3], you can do a[0:15], but you can't do a[15].  So the real error is in numCheck, where digits[2] eventually fails because digits is not long enough.  As an aside to the OP, I would suggest using regex to solve this problem much more concisely.

Comment: @BlivetWidget I see what you're saying, but I'm only checking to see if the number of digits in digits[]. If the condition isn't met shouldn't it just move on like the previous steps? I'll take a look at regex, thanks

Comment: oops, funnily enough the tutorial I'm watching is for regex but he was showing how inefficient it was without it

Comment: @KernelPource You are not currently checking the length of digits, only of lists within digits.  You are assuming digits always has a length of 3, but if there are not enough '-' characters, digits will be shorter.